# My model is translucent in solid mode

Tags: modeling, visibility

[image]

I have had this problem since I fixed my previous problem of have my model disappearing when I closed in on it. I have tried the "Limit selection to visible" at the bottom of the screen and some other method but end up nowhere. If you can help please do so If you need the .blend file I can provide

Comment: Use "limit selection to visible" https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRyUY.jpg